# Make a StackPanel and its contents "draggable" in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a UserControl in the form of:

```xml
<UserControl>   
    <Grid>         
          <!-- Content Here-->    
      <StackPanel>   <!-- I want this element to be draggable within the usercontrol. -->    
         <Label Name = "Header" />  
         <Button />
         <Button />
         <Button />             
         </StackPanel>    
   <Grid>             
</UserControl>
```

My end result is to have a control with buttons (part of the usercontrol) that can be dragged around..? That is, moveable ... within the UserControl

Ive read about Thumb but I am not sure how to use it...Any ideas or examples would be great.Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by draggable, to change its possition inside the usercontrol o to drop the panel on another control?

Comment: No just move it around ... Not drag and Drop...

Comment: [Check this code project solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38830033/2507782)

Comment: Checkout this [code project solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38830033/2507782) exactly as par your need

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A very simple way to do it would be to use mouse events

First off, wrap your `StackPanel` in a `Canvas` so it can be easily positioned according to where the user drags it

Next, add `MouseDown` and `MouseUp` events to the `StackPanel`. You may need to give your `StackPanel` a background color for it to receive mouse events.

In the `MouseDown` event, attach a `MouseMove` event handler to the `StackPanel` and have the panel [capture the mouse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.capturemouse.aspx) so all mouse events will get handled by the `StackPanel`.

In the `MouseUp` event, detach the `MouseMove` event and release your mouse capture.

In the `MouseMove` event, change the `Canvas.Top` and `Canvas.Left` properties of the panel based on the current Mouse position. You will need a check here to determine if the mouse is outside of the `UserControl` too so the `StackPanel` can't be dragged off screen.

And that's it, very basic drag drop :)

Comment: Thanks Rachel. This really gave me a kickstart!

Answer (score 2):

Here is an actual working example of a Draggable Rectangle in WPF, This is exactly what Rachel is talking about above.

You can put any `UserControl`/`StackPanel`/`Grid` etc inside the `Canvas` tag.

I made this because I was having an issue dragging a `StackPanel`, the problem was actually that I had set a Margin on the panel so it was being offset.

This won't skip around when you drag it.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Canvas x:Name="canvas" Background="Transparent" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="PreviewDown" PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp="PreviewUp" MouseMove="MoveMouse">
            <Rectangle x:Name="Rectangle" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Fill="Black" Height="85" Margin="0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="82" />
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

`XAML`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private object movingObject;
        private double firstXPos, firstYPos;

        private void PreviewDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            firstXPos = e.GetPosition(Rectangle).X;
            firstYPos = e.GetPosition(Rectangle).Y;

            movingObject = sender;
        }

        private void PreviewUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            movingObject = null;
        }

        private void MoveMouse(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed && sender == movingObject)
            {
                double newLeft = e.GetPosition(canvas).X - firstXPos - canvas.Margin.Left;

                Rectangle.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, newLeft);

                double newTop = e.GetPosition(canvas).Y - firstYPos - canvas.Margin.Top;

                Rectangle.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, newTop);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`MainWindow.cs`

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to handle the mouseclick on the button and change its position while moving the mouse.

So the steps will be:

1. Add a handler to the button. Mouseclick for example (or mousedown)
2. When you receive a mouseclick add a handler to mousemove.
3. Check the movement of the mouse and change the position of the button
4. Remove the handler after releasing the mouse button.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any specific method but intuitively, you may add an event handler to drag method of the control you want to move, and in that method, you may render the control to a bitmap, make that bitmap follow your mouse pointer, and hide the original control. When dropped (mouse released), it should simply set the original control's coordinates to mouse coordinates, dispose of the bitmap, and re-enable the visibility of the control.

Answer (score 0):

There are some tutorials available for this on MSDN and other places. Try the following link for WPF drag and drop.

[WPF Drag and Drop](http://wpftutorial.net/DragAndDrop.html)

Comment: Thanks for the link...This isnt Drag And Drop exactly, its just making a control moveable...kind of like Windows DragMove().

Answer (score 0):

You should give a chance to the [avalondock project](http://avalondock.codeplex.com/).

This allows you to create rich layout features, like Visual Studio does (floating, docking, etc.).

I'm confident this would help you.