# C# WPF PRISM - Make UserControl Draggable

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

I already found a solution ([How to make a user control draggable on screen like a window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13865517/how-to-make-a-user-control-draggable-on-screen-like-a-window)), but it doesn't work the way i wanted. In this solution only the content of the UserControl is draggable, but i open my UserDialog with the ShowDialog method, so the UserControl is a seperate Dialog (https://prismlibrary.com/docs/wpf/dialog-service.html).

Is there any equivalent to the DragMove() method for the UserControl?

Comment: if the default prism dialog had the option to be draggable, that would indeed be great

Comment: Why not make this a window if you want the user to be able to drag it?

Comment: While it is possible to make a UserControl draggable (and quite easy too) it comes with a big limitation. The parent Window does not allow content to be rendered outside the client area. This means your UserControl will be clipped when the user tries to drag it out of the client area. I would say this disqualifies the UserControl to serve as a draggable dialog. In case the dialog is modal you could consider to make it a fixed dialog. The user could drag it by dragging the application Window.  Otherwise, replace the UserControl with a Window or Popup (like Andy suggested).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if I understood correctly, but you want a behavior that when a user control is dragged you want the parent window to be dragged. So here it is :

```
public class DragParentWindowBehavior : Behavior<UserControl>
    {
        private Window parentWindow;

        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            AssociatedObject.Loaded += AssociatedObject_Loaded;
            AssociatedObject.Unloaded += AssociatedObject_Unloaded;
            AssociatedObject.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown += AssociatedObject_MouseLeftButtonDown;
        }

        private void AssociatedObject_Unloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            parentWindow = null;
        }

        private void AssociatedObject_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
           //We get the parent window here. because the behavior is attached to the view way before it is shown.
            parentWindow = Window.GetWindow(AssociatedObject);
        }

        private void AssociatedObject_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            parentWindow?.DragMove();
        }

        protected override void OnDetaching()
        {
            AssociatedObject.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown -= AssociatedObject_MouseLeftButtonDown;
            AssociatedObject.Loaded -= AssociatedObject_Loaded;
            AssociatedObject.Unloaded -= AssociatedObject_Unloaded;

            parentWindow = null;
        }
    }
```

This is how you use it in XAML :

```
<UserControl x:Class="Prism1.Modules.ModuleName.Views.DraggableControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Prism1.Modules.ModuleName.Views" 
             xmlns:Behaviors="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors" 
             xmlns:mvvm="clr-namespace:Prism1.Core.Mvvm;assembly=Prism1.Core"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Behaviors:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <mvvm:DragParentWindowBehavior></mvvm:DragParentWindowBehavior>
    </Behaviors:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Margin="5">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Message}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
        <Button Command="{Binding CloseDialogCommand}" CommandParameter="true" Content="OK" Width="75" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,10,0,0" Grid.Row="1" IsDefault="True" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: It works perfectly, thanks! Only one small thing needs to be changed. The controls are not accessible for the user, so you have to replace AssociatedObject.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown with AssociatedObject.MouseLeftButtonDown.